# How can i do a split from a variable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I want to be able to separate the value of a variable by "\" and save it in a variable. I have in the variable "C:\Users\admin\test\test.txt" and I want to get only the name of the file so I can search by name

```
Sub Main()
        Dim numbers = {"prova.txt", "prova2.txt", "prova3.txt"}
        Dim prova As New ArrayList
        For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\manager\Audio", Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.txt")
            Dim words As String() = foundFile.Split(New Char() {"\"})
            Console.WriteLine(words)
            prova.Add(foundFile)
        Next


        Console.Read()
    End Sub
```

I did that for a test.

```
Dim s As String = "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Perls\Main"

        ' Split the string on the backslash character.
        Dim parts As String() = s.Split(New Char() {"\"c})
        Console.WriteLine(parts)
```

ERROR output on cmd -> System.String[]

Comment: Use the `System.IO.Path` class to manipulate file and folder paths.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your current solution?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing i cant do the split. Output on cmd: System.string[]

Comment: You need to print each value in the resulting array, not the array itself.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(parts)` outputs the array, but since an array doesn't override `ToString` you just see it's type name `System.string[]`. You can use `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", parts))`

Comment: Console.WriteLine is essentially calling .ToString on parts. Unless .ToString is overridden it will return the fully qualified name of the type. parts is an Array to String. You would need to refer to a specific element of the array to get the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
Dim s As String = "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Perls\Main"
Dim finalstring As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s)
Console.WriteLine(finalstring)
```

That gets the filename without its extension and prints it to the console

If you still want to use the Split function , use

```
Dim parts As String() = Split(s,"\")
For x As Integer = 0 To Ubound(parts) - 1
   Console.WriteLine(parts(x) & vbNewLine)
Next
```

Comment: The second option should be `s.Split("\"c)` and then `parts(parts.GetUpperBound(0))` or `parts.Last()`.

Comment: With your second option the error will be the same as the OP.